# how to share post on facebook or google using URLScheme

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, google-plus, share

I want to share an HTML link on facebook without install SDK like WhatsApp or twitter. I am using below code for share a link on facebook. But I want to share the post to direct app without an open safari browser.
Please tell me this is possible or not.I have searched alot but not find any solution.

```
//For share twitter

let urlWhats = "twitter://post?message=\(fileURL)"
let urlString = urlWhats.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)
let whatsappURL = URL(string: urlString!)
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL!)
{
    UIApplication.shared.open(whatsappURL!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}


//For Facebook
let shareURL = "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + url

if let url = URL(string:shareURL)
{
    let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: url, entersReaderIfAvailable: true)
    vc.delegate=self
    present(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

For sharing in FB make use of 'FacebookShare'

```
import FBSDKShareKit

class yourViewController: UIViewController {

func shareContentInFB()  {


let content = FBSDKShareLinkContent()

        content.contentURL =  URL(string: "http://yourURL/")
        content.quote = "Hey !!!!"
        let dialog : FBSDKShareDialog = FBSDKShareDialog()
        dialog.fromViewController = self
        dialog.shareContent = content
        dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogMode.automatic
        dialog.show()
     }
}
```

You cannot prefill text in fb using this, if you have to do it then make use of Fb graph API

Comment: I want to share without Facebook SDK install.

Comment: Then use Native sharing

Comment: Native sharing  means?

Comment: Using UIActivityViewController, Content can be shared to all the installed application in your device

Comment: But I want to share without UIActivityViewController. I have created a custom share dialog.